# Quantum light reflections: in & out same quanta?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, reflection, refraction

A "bounce" theory of light reflection is required to assume Michelson-Morley (less ether interpretations) demonstrates c constancy. An incoming quantum, George, is the outgoing quantum.

A "catch & throw" theory would suggest that M-M does not demonstrate c constancy, that George arrives and Mary departs. Like a baseball pitcher's fastball being returned by the catcher at his own velocity. Hence, per such a  theory, M-M would demonstrate nothing about c+v.

What does quantum theory say about this matter?

Similarly, please, in regard to refraction.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are no measurable delays in reflection but it wouldn't matter anyway in the Michelson Morley experiment. If there were any delay it would be the same for either arm of the interferometer.

Comment: Thanks, @Bill Alsept.  Very nice. Do you feel/think a non-delay implies a counter to the catch&throw model?

Comment: I don't know if there is a delay or not. I said as far as I know there is no measurable delay. Also photons don't bounce. They are absorbed and then I knew photon is emitted in a random direction.

Comment: thanks. Absorption is perhaps even necessary for c+v to hold, at least as far as M-M is concerned; an incoming quantum could not (?) be said to be the outgoing quantit(y/um). If the outgoing quantum carried a flag identifying the reflector's idea as to its wavelength, would the emitter recognize that wavelength as that of its emission?